# django how to generate QR code in my model

Tags: django, django-models, qr-code

I'm new to Django and I came to the part where I need to generate a QR barcode for each product in my App

I found two libraries `django-qr-code` and `django-qrcode`

what is the deference between these two libraries and which one I should use

the other point is there any good tutorial I can follow to generate a QR code in a model ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`django-qr-code`](https://pypi.org/project/django-qr-code/) since it is being actively maintained, whereas [`django-qrcode`](https://pypi.org/project/django-qrcode/) hasn't seen an update since 2011.

Now about a documentation/tutorial I believe you can find one in the `django-qr-code` repository [usage section](https://github.com/dprog-philippe-docourt/django-qr-code#usage).